# R and dplyr - how to write efficient code for load data from database

Tags: r, dplyr

I use dbplyr for getting data from our sql database. Basicaly I work like this:

1) I load same data from one table, for example:

```
flights <- 
  tbl(delta, "us") %>% 
  select(id, origin) %>% 
  collect()
```

2) Then I use this data filtering data from other tables etc.

```
passangers <-
  tbl(customers, "all") %>% 
  filter(flight_id %in% flights$id) %>% 
  filter(year == "2018") %>% 
  collect()

payments <- 
      tbl(incoming_payments, "all") %>% 
      filter(flight_id %in% flights$id) %>% 
      filter(year == "2018") %>% 
      collect()

contact_data <-
      tbl(emails, "all") %>% 
          filter(customer_id %in% passangers $id) %>% 
          filter(type == "email") %>% 
          collect()
```

This works well until I need to load data from more tables. Since this way im creating dataframe for each query and I know how to load data from just one table by one query Im creating so many dataframes and code is quite repeated even in this simple example.

So my question is if there is a way how to write similar query more simplier ideally with only one created dataframe. But with ability to filter data like I do (Im filtering only flight_ids that are present in flights dataframe etc.)

Comment: Try `sqldf`, might be the most relevant package, never used it before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `tbl()`, would this work?

```
table_names = c("customers","incoming_payments","emails")

extractFilter = function(x)
  tbl(x,"all") %>%  #eval(x) here?
  filter(flight_id %in% flights$id) %>% 
  filter(year == "2018") %>% 
  collect()


results = lapply(table_names,extractFilter)
```

This way you get all the data frames in the results list. You could join them all adding a pipe to `purr::reduce(full_join,by="join_variable")`